# Creating dynamic json from already existing json

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting one json in this structure:

```
{
data: { 
    ads: [
            {           
            name: "0",
            id: "81"
            },
            {           
            name: "0",
            id: "82"
            }           
        ]
    }
}
```

i want to create one more json from the existing one like this.

```
{
json{
    81:[
            {           
                name: "a",
                id: "81"
            },
        ]
    82:[
        {           
                name: "c",
                id: "82"
            }
    ]
  }

}
```

I am not getting how to create according to the id. Can anyone help me in this. using javascript i am want to create this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to achieve this:

```
var obj = {
    data: { 
        ads: [
            {           
            name: "0",
            id: "81"
            },
            {           
            name: "0",
            id: "82"
            }           
        ]
    }
};

var newobj = {
  json: {}
};
for(var i in obj.data.ads) {
    var a = obj.data.ads[i];
    if(!(a.id in newobj.json)) {
        newobj.json[a.id] = [];
    }
    newobj.json[a.id].push({ name: a.name, id: a.id });
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qTgEA/) to demonstrate.

Comment: document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle. Your fiddle fails to load for me in Chrome

Comment: here i gave sample. i will get lot of contents with the same id like for eg id 81 contains 5 objects and id 82 contains 3 objects i have to store that in the particular array@RGraham

Comment: @Priya Slightly more complicated in that you need to check if the element exists. Updated answer and fiddle.